# A wordpress theme which background is sticky and the content is movable

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I need a wordpress theme or any plugin which looks like https://www.haldiram.com/ this and work like this. I want to make same home page and header in wordpress, can anyone help me about this in wordpress. Tell me how the same thing is possible using any plugin or using any theme, or tell any another way to do this. I try make background like this using css but didn't get success. i dosen't need exact same but if someting smillar to this tell me.

Answer (score 0):

The important thing is to add the `background-attachment: fixed;` CSS property.

Also you need to have the page content height bigger than the window in order to see the scroll effect.

In the demo below I added a `min-height: 2500px;` on the `.site-content` page element.

```css
body {
    background-image: url("https://www.haldiram.com/themes/haldiram/images/bg.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}

.site-content {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1200px;
    min-height: 2500px;
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 2rem 3rem;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="site-content">
  <h1>This is a Heading</h1>
  <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
</div><!-- .site-content end -->

</body>
</html>
```